# Quickfilter component width with 100% - Material UI

Tags: material-ui, datagrid

I'm learning to use Material UI for React js.
I'm implementing the DataGrid control with the Quick filter option.

However, how do I make its width occupy the entire screen?

I didn't find in the documentation if this was possible.
See attached image for better understanding.

Thanks!

```
<DataGrid
    components={{ Toolbar: GridToolbar }}
    componentsProps={{
      toolbar: {
        showQuickFilter: true,
        quickFilterProps: { debounceMs: 500 },
      },
    }}
  />
```

[SampleImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiraT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue resolved

```
function QuickSearchToolbar() {
return (
    <Box
        sx={{
            pl: 1,
            pr: 1,
            pb: 2,
            pt: 1,
            display: 'flex',
        }}
    >
        <GridToolbarQuickFilter
            style={{ flex: 1 }}

            quickFilterParser={(searchInput: string) =>
                searchInput
                    .split(',')
                    .map((value) => value.trim())
                    .filter((value) => value !== '')
            }
            debounceMs={600}
        />
    </Box>
)
```

}

```
  <DataGrid
                    {...rest}
                    localeText={ptBR.components.MuiDataGrid.defaultProps.localeText}
                    pageSize={50}
                    rowsPerPageOptions={[50]}
                    getRowId={(row) => row.ID}
                    components={{
                        Toolbar: QuickSearchToolbar,
                        LoadingOverlay: LinearProgress
                    }}
                    componentsProps={{
                        toolbar: {
                            showquickfilter: true,
                            quickFilterProps: { debounceMs: 600 },
                        },
                    }}
                />
```